# Creating an associative array from two variables containing lists of same length

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have two variables, called variable 1, and variable 2,
one contains a list of names, and one contains a list of values, and the lists are the same length. How would I go about creating an associative array where the first name in the list of names was the key of one of the items in the array, and the first value in the list of values was the index of that key. For example

```
declare -A AgeDatabase
variable1=John Mary Sam
variable2=15 16 19

$ echo $AgeDatabase[John]
15
$ echo $AgeDatabase[Mary]
16
$ echo $AgeDatabase[Sam]
19
```

In this example, I know I could have manually set these values, however I want to automate the process of setting the values, using some sort of loop, I'm unsure how and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays for the lists:

```
#!/bin/bash
names=(John Mary Sam)
ages=(15 16 19)

declare -A AgeDatabase

for ((i=0; i<${#names[@]}; ++i)) ; do
    AgeDatabase[${names[i]}]=${ages[i]}
done

echo ${AgeDatabase[John]}
```

Note the syntax for printing array values and assigning to them.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare -A AgeDatabase=( ["John"]="15" ["Mary"]="16" ["sam"]="19")

for age in "${!AgeDatabase[@]}"; do echo "$sound - ${AgeDatabase["$age"]}"; done
```